# Rails: Jquery Select Menu connected to School Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am currently trying to create a select menu on the index page of a school model and I am having trouble trying to make this work. I am looking at a peers code for help but mine won't work and I am still noobish to JS. Can anyone take a look and see what the issue is and what I may have to add? Thank you, all suggestions are much appreciated! :)

**Index HTML**

```
<div id='MainContentContainer'>
<div class='MainContentArea'>
<div class='MainContent'>
<h1>Choose your school:</h1>
<div class='SchoolSelection'>
<select id="SchoolSelect">
<option>State School</option>
<option>Private School</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class='MainContentButton'>
<a href='/' id='continue'>
<div class="MainContentBtn">
Continue
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

 <script>
    $('#continue').click(function() {
        var singleValues = $("#SchoolSelect").val();
        $.cookie("schoolproject", singleValues);
    })
        </script>
```

**School Controller**

```
class SchoolsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if request.cookies["schoolproject"] == 'State School'
      redirect_to '/schools/state-school'
      return
    elsif request.cookies["schoolproject"] == 'Private School'
      redirect_to '/schools/private-school'
      return
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html  #index.html.erb
      format.js 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you describe what the issue is please?

Comment: @gideon The issue is that, when I click the continue button, it does not but refresh the page instead of saving a cookie and sending it to the link of localhost..../schools/state-school

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not preventing the default action of the link click:

```
$('#continue').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.cookie('schoolproject', $('#SchoolSelect').val());
}
```

On a side note, `div` tags inside of an `a` tag is invalid HTML. I would suggest either swapping those around, or converting your `div` tags to `span` tags.

Comment: I just changed the js to what you provided and it still does not store a cookie or move onto the next appropriate page

Comment: I need more detail, then, about what you're trying to accomplish. Firstly, are you using JQuery or another library? If you're using JQuery, what plugin are you using for the $.cookie()? That's not native to JQuery. If you're using something else, what's the library? Basically, I need to see the API for that call to know why it doesn't work. Lastly, what is the desired action once the cookie is saved? Do you want to reload the page, go to a new URL, or simply show some other data, like display a new DIV?

Comment: I would like to reload a new page and when it does reload that page I would like it to be that page everytime the user relogs into the website, and I am not using a cookie

Comment: Use either window.location.href or window.location.reload() for reloading the page. Here's the documentation [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location). Now, I'm confused when you say that you're not using a cookie. Both your client-side and server-side code uses a cookie. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: I meant I am not using a plugin sorry x), just jquery cookie

Comment: Are you including this file [JQuery Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)? $.cookie() is not native JQuery, so you need this plugin for your code to work. You'll also find the plugin's documentation there.

Comment: That would make sense, I will try now :)

Comment: ahh scratch that! Cookie saved! :) but it won't redirect? Any suggestions?